# Audit trail information for GROUP / authorityContainer on Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I'm trying to find when a particular group is created and who has created it,but unfortunately I couldn't find this information in the **Node Browser** as well as **database** also.

I noticed the **cm:auditable** aspect is missing on the group node(*here GROUP_DEMO*).

Is there any specific reason, alfresco ignored audit information on the groups(authorityContainer)?

Please let me know, is that possible to retrieve this information from any other place to find the group creation date details?

Please refer the below screenshot.

[image]